# Filtering a django queryset based on computed values

Tags: python, django, filter, django-queryset

I'm running a bunch of filters on one of my models. Specifically, I'm doing something like this in one of my views:

```
cities = City.objects.filter(name__icontains=request.GET['name']
cities = City.objects.filter(population__gte=request.GET['lowest_population']
return cities
```

Now I'd like to add one other, different type of filter. Specifically, I'd like to include only those cities that are a certain distance away from a particular zip code. I already have the relevant function for this, i.e. something like:

```
distanceFromZipCode(city, zipCode)
# This returns 110 miles, for example
```

How do I combine django's queryset filtering with this additional filter I'd like to add? I know that if cities were merely a list, I could just use .filter() and pass in the appropriate lambda (e.g. return true if the distance from the relevant zip code is <100).

But I'm dealing with query sets, not simple lists, so how would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of the issue is that you're trying to mix sql filters, which are done within the db, and a python filter, which is done once the records are materialized from the db. You can't do that without taking the items from the database and then filtering on top of that.

You can't, do this via your python function, but you can do this via geodjango:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/#distance-queries

```
cites = cities.filter(distance_lt=101)
```

would get you what you want

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to mix a Python method with a database query, and that's not possible.  Either you write the SQL to perform the distance calculation (fast), or you fetch every row and call your method (slow).  Django filters simply translate parameters into a SQL WHERE clause, so if you can't express it in SQL, you probably can't express it in a filter.

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing the location of the city as geometry you can use a distance spatial filter chained with the rest of your filters:

```
from django.contrib.gis.measure import D
zipCode = ZipCode.objects.all()[0]
cities = City.objects.filter(point__distance_lte=(zipCode.geom, D(mi=110)))
```

This assumes you have a ZipCode model with geometry of each zip code and the geometry is stored in a field called 'geom' and your City object has a point field called 'point'.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should use the [Queryset object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects), and define complex filter method inside [custom manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/).

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Q


class CityManager(models.Manager):

    def get_filtered_cities(self, name=None, lowest_population=None, zip_code=None):
        query = Q()

        if(name):
            query = Q(name__icontains=name)

        if(lowest_population):
            query = query & Q(population__gte=lowest_population)

        if(zip_code):
            pass #other query object

        return self.get_query_set().filter(query)
```